# RadComboBox dropdown below ONLY

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

Is there a way to force the dropdown of a RadComboBox to ONLY appear below and never above regardless of what the control feels would be the most visible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting the `EnableScreenBoundaryDetection` property to `false` should do the trick.

Comment: Love it! so simple - why is it not in their documentation??

Comment: Thank you. Been bugging me for a while, even with ExpandDirection="Down" set.

Comment: Thanks! I also don't understand why it's not in the documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/search.aspx?q=EnableScreenBoundaryDetection&ppId=561&pId=583&start=0

There also appear to be some strange issues when the dropdown opens upwards. For instance, it will expand past the top of the page if the list contains enough checkboxes. If it expands downwards, the dropdown will become scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Add this property in telerik dropdown

You can change direction dynamically also

```
ExpandDirection="Up"
```